# Is direct image of finite morphism exact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite morphism of schemes (or algebraic varieties if you prefer). Then is the direct image functor $f_*:Mod(O_X)\to Mod(O_Y)$ exact?

If we restrict to quasi-coherent modules, then $f_*:Qch(X)\to Qch(Y)$ is exact by Serre vanishing.

Comment: Do you have a motivation for this? I am struggling to think of a good example of where you would be interested in non-quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules (but that may just be my ignorance). A more interesting question, to me, is whether $f_\ast$ is exact for $\mathbf{Ab}(X_\mathrm{Zar})\to \mathbf{Ab}(Y_\mathrm{zar})$ (where $\mathbf{Ab}$ is the category of abelian sheaves). The answer to this is no (for instance see Bhargav Bhatt's nice comment on this post: https://mathoverflow.net/a/102414), but it is true if we replace the Zariski topology by the (pro-)etale topology

Comment: (see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09A8), which is usually enough in practice.

Comment: Dear @AlexYoucis, I am very glad to see you there. My question arises from (3.4), p.159 of "Duality between $D(X)$ and $D(\hat{X})$ with its application to Picard sheaves" by Mukai, 1981. The situation is as follows. Let $\varphi:Y\to X$ be an isogeny of abelian varieties. Then Mukai uses the notation $\varphi_*:D(Mod(O_Y))\to D(Mod(O_X))$ for the derived functor of $\varphi_*:Mod(O_Y)\to Mod(O_X)$. At other places, he uses notation like $R\varphi_*$. This leads me to guess that he has the exactness of $\varphi_*$ in mind.